# How to install a custom made application on Windows phone 8

Tags: 8.0, apps, side-loading

I have made my own custom made application for my Windows phone 8 and now i want to install it. I tried manually installing my application by going into Store → SD Card; but it seems it only recognize applications downloaded from Windows store.

Because of this I am unable to find my applications XAP file thus installing it. Do you have any idea how to install custom made applications in Windows 8

Comment: I do not know why, but I have noticed that a lot of people have had this issue when they do not have an SD card installed. For whatever reason, the Windows Phone must use the SD card to store these types of files. I tried this on mine and without the SD card, the phone is totally confused, with the SD card, all goes perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Windows Phone SDK installed, and have a developer account, you can run the "**Windows Phone Developer Registration**" program (Search for the title in quotes in your start screen).

There are two ways to get your program on the phone from this point. The first is to connect your phone to your PC with Visual Studio on it, turn on and unlock your phone, switch the build dropdown menu from emulator to device and debug your program. It will install the program on your phone as long as there is nothing wrong with your program.

The second way is to open your start screen, search for "**Application Deployment**", select your XAP file (it will be in the bin/debug or bin/release folder of your startup project. Then select deploy. Your phone must be turned on and unlocked as well.

Comment: is it possible to install xap files without a developer account?

Comment: You can create an app with http://apps.windowsstore.com This allows you to dev unlock one device. All of my phones are already dev unlocked so I canot test the above steps with this method. But you can unlock one device by this site.

Answer (score 3):

Is your phone developer unlocked? That's a prerequisite. If not, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the explanation how to developer unlock your phone. After you have unlocked your phone, you will need to use XapDeploy.exe to install the app on your phone. XapDeploy.exe is automatically installed with the Windows Phone 8 SDK, so you should have it on your machine. The instructions to use the app are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).